# Int to Decimal Conversion - Insert decimal point at specified location

Tags: c#, int, decimal, type-conversion, decimal-point

I have the following int 7122960
I need to convert it to  71229.60

Any ideas on how to convert the int into a decimal and insert the decimal point in the correct location?

Comment: And if you need to insert a decimal point after `n` digits, divide by `10**n`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
int i = 7122960;
decimal d = (decimal)i / 100;
```

Comment: For clarity, it might be worth using `(decimal)i / 100M` to highlight the fact that the division happens after the conversion to decimal (as it must). (As it is, the 100 is being automatically converted to decimal anyway, so it's just a clarity thing.)

Answer (score 5):

Simple math.

```
double result = ((double)number) / 100.0;
```

Although you may want to use `decimal` rather than `double`: [decimal vs double! - Which one should I use and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1165761/866022)

Answer (score 4):

Declare it as a `decimal` which uses the `int` variable and divide this by 100

```
int number = 700
decimal correctNumber = (decimal)number / 100;
```

Edit: Bala was faster with his reaction