# How to concat two integers converting into float value in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I am working on Windows Phone Application.

I need to concat two values which are integers and the result should be changed into float value.

For example, a = 120 and b = 3. Then result c = 120.3 which is float value. How to do this task?

Comment: Did you try to convert the integer to string and do a concatenation ?

Comment: Also try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044603/int-to-decimal-conversion-insert-decimal-point-at-specified-location

Comment: The above will not work if b has more than 1 digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `float.Parse`?

```
float value = float.Parse(string.Format("{0}.{1}", a.ToString(), b.ToString()));
```

Comment: This is the way to do it, but you don't need to call .ToString for a and b because string.Format does it automatically.

Comment: @Ashigore Calling `ToString()` lets you prevent the value from boxing.

Answer (score 4):

```
 int a = 120;
 int b = 3;
 string s = a + "." + b;
 float f = float.Parse(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sample code:

```
int a = 120;
int b = 3;
string c = a.ToString() + '.' + b.ToString();
float f = float.Parse(c,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using this shorter one:

```
float f = float.Parse(string.Concat(a, ".", b));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do is:
dim FB = B * 0.1, C = A + FB as Float 
or
as each part as string and 
S for string on your variables
SC = SA +"." +SB
And convert string to value
this logic should work in most versions of C and BASIC and most likely other languages too