# Long to decimal with decimal point at a specific position

Tags: c#, decimal, long-integer, bigdecimal, decimal-point

In C#, I have a long that I need to convert to a decimal. The problem is that I want to put the decimal point at a specific position in the long.

For example, let's say I have the following number as a long:

```
long l = 123456789
```

When converting to a decimal with the floating point at the third position, I want to have the following:

```
decimal d = 123456.789
```

To give you an example, the function would ideally be something like the [BigDecimal.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28long,%20int%29) in Java that allows you to give a long and a position to put the decimal point, and it returns the correct value.

I know one of the solution would be to format the long as a string with the correct decimal point position and then convert it back to a decimal. Another solution would be to multiply the long by 10<sup>-Decimal places wanted</sup>, but I'm wondering if there's a better alternative to this.

Comment: Are you trying to convert to decimal or double? They're not the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in the title. I fixed it. I'm attempting to convert from long to decimal.

Comment: Strongly related: [Int to Decimal Conversion - Insert decimal point at specified location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044603/int-to-decimal-conversion-insert-decimal-point-at-specified-location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Decimal` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1c1a6x(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes different constituent parts. You'll need to do a bit of bitshifting to get the exponent into all the relevant sections, but that shouldn't be too hard. If you know that your value won't be more than 62 bits in magnitude, that would make things easier, too.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you divide by 1000 (or 10^N where N is the number of decimal places)?

Comment: That's the purpose of my question. I'm wondering if there's a C# function similar to BigDecimal.valueOf that allows you to convert it without you having to do these kind of calculations.

Comment: Apparently, even if it is a bit more work to get the sections, the Decimal constructor can do this kind of work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1c1a6x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
long l = 123456789L;
int decplaces = 3;

decimal divisor =(decimal) Math.Pow(10, decplaces);
decimal d = l/divisor;
```

Comment: Probably not precise if `decplaces` is something like `25`. Or maybe the strange rules for converting into `decimal` avtually save you?

Comment: when int decplace = 25;   d= 0.0000000000000000123456789  (LinqPad comes in very handy)

Comment: It still works for decplaces = 28, but at 29, it throws an exception says it's too small for a decimal.

Comment: I was considering the fact that `Math.Pow(10, 25)` returns a `double` whose value internally cannot be `1E+25` exactly. It will be `1.0000000000000000905969664E+25` instead. Then one could fear that the corresponding decimal would become `10000000000000000905969664m`. But it actually becomes `10000000000000000000000000m` by some kind of magic. So I think your method is accurate after all.

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a loop to multiply by `0.1m` the correct number of times, i.e. `numberOfDecimalPlacesWanted` iterations of the loop.